Issue with requestAVAssetForVideo in iOS18
I'm encountering an issue on iOS 18:
I use the following code to get the video path in the photos kit:
[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:videoOptions resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    BOOL yesOrNo = [self isInCloudForInfo:info];
    NSString *localPath = nil;
    if (!yesOrNo && [asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
        localPath = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL].absoluteString;
    }
   // Do something with localPath...
}]

When I use [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath], it returns NO. Also, the .duration of the AVURLAsset init with localPath returns 0, but this video can be played via AVPlayer.
When I get localPath by  localPath = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL].relativePath, and [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath] returns YES, but the AVURLAsset can't play the video with "You don't have permission." error.
How can I resolve is?
Here are some links I found on Google that might be relevant:

https://medium.com/@mi9nxi/ios-18-phasset-url-from-requestavasset-09c67fd069f1
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/758691
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756811

Must I use Photos Kit? If so, I'll need to make significant changes to adapt to iOS18

Found any solution?

https://medium.com/@mi9nxi/ios-18-phasset-url-from-requestavasset-09c67fd069f1
Use relativePath  instead of absoluteString  will fix it.

This article actually says to use someUrl.absoluteString
